# Is it safe to split a path on '/' to parse it?

Tags: path, posix, dirname

I am trying to get all directories in a path. For example, from `a/b/c/d.e` I would like to get `a`, `a/b`, and `a/b/c`. I can achieve this by calling functions like posix`dirname` several times. The problem is with paths like `a/b/c/`. I would like to get `a`, `a/b`, and `a/b/c`. Since there is a `/` following `c`, `c` should be a directory that I would like to list. But functions like `dirname` return `a/b` instead of `a/b/c` when given `a/b/c/` as input.

Can I just split on `/` to get the list of directories or is there an edge case where this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only special cases I know are

1. with file name at the end
2. with a `/` at the end
3. with a folder name called `a.e` (may or may be not at the end)
4. symbolic link
5. Windows path (which is using `\` but I think it is not applying in your case)
6. User input error, put multiple `/`. e.g. `/tmp//something` which is supported in some programmes

If your function is supporting all of the above cases, I think it is fine.